# Upgrading the Gradle Wrapper

Tags: gradle

I am working with the [gradle wrapper](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html) on my project which produces some files to download and install gradle on the host machine.  These files are checked into the project.   My project structure looks like:

```
/common/common.gradle
/module-a/build.gradle
/module-b/build.gradle
/module-c/build.gradle
```

Each of my projects apply common settings from a shared common.gradle file which contains the task:

```
task wrapper(type: Wrapper) { 
    distributionUrl = "http://<nexus>:8081/nexus/content/repositories/thirdparty/org/gradle/gradle-bin/1.10/gradle-bin-1.10-bin.zip"
}
```

In each project, this allows me to run "gradle wrapper" and produce the gradlew script which will execute a downloaded version of gradle.  When I look inside my gradle-wrapper.properties which is generated by this task (in each sub-project), my distributionUrl is this absolute path from my wrapper task, instead of a dynamic/relative reference to the setting in common.gradle.

So what happens when I want to upgrade to the next version of gradle?  Do I need to re-run gradle wrapper in each project?  Is there some way to have the distrbutionUrl reference a shared property?

Any insights would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you talking about a single build, or many builds? The Gradle Wrapper should be installed once per build, not once per (sub)project.

Comment: hey Peter, it looks like i'm doing it once per-subproject.  I edited my question to clarify.  How would I go about doing it once per build?  Should I drop a build.gradle at the root level?

Comment: Only the root `build.gradle` should declare a wrapper task (in recent Gradle versions this task is even declared automatically), and consequently the wrapper task should only be executed for the root project. You should only have one `gradlew` and `gradlew.bat` script per build (in the root directory), and one `gradle/wrapper` directory.

Comment: ok, that makes sense, so how do you run gradlew then?  You have to do "../gradlew" in each sub-project?

Comment: There isn't yet an official solution, but there are some simple shell scripts floating around (e.g. from the SpringSource folks) that you can put on your PATH and that will search for `gradlew` upwards in the directory hierarchy. I highly recommend this approach. Longer term, there will be a `gradlew` binary that gets installed like a regular application.

Comment: Thanks Peter.  It seems this is documented by GRADLE-1378.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem for now by running the gradle wrapper only in the parent directory so my project structure looks like:

```
project1
project2
<gradlew files>
```

On my CI server I then use the -p option to specify the sub directory.  Like this:

```
./gradlew -p project1 <target>
```

This works for us for now until gradlew becomes a binary as Peter mentioned.  See [GRADLE-1378](https://issues.gradle.org/browse/GRADLE-1378).

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Gradle website](https://gradle.org/install/#with-the-gradle-wrapper) the wrapper can be upgraded with:
`./gradlew wrapper --gradle-version=8.2.1 --distribution-type=bin`
to update the version and `/gradlew tasks` to download the ZIP file.